# jQuery - How to pass 'this' to a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I pass `$(this)` into a function. In my example below I want to populate the address textbox with the value of the selected drop-down option label but only if the value selected is not empty.

The following doesn't work?

```js
$("#AddressId").change(function () {
  $("#Address").val(function(index, val) {
      val = $(this).val();
      return val === "" ? "" : $('option:selected', this).text();
  }, this).trigger("change");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="AddressId">
 <option value="">-- Please select --</option>
 <option value="1">xyz street</option>
 ...
</select>

<input id="Address" name="Address" value="" type="text">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve this store the `this` reference of `#AddressId` in a variable the `change` event handler. You can then use that variable in the inner `val()` function, like this:

```js
$("#AddressId").change(function() {
  var $addressId = $(this);
  
  $("#Address").val(function(index, val) {
    val = $addressId.val();
    return val === "" ? "" : $('option:selected', $addressId).text();
  }, this).trigger("change");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="AddressId">
   <option value="">-- Please select --</option>
   <option value="1">xyz street</option>
 </select>

<input id="Address" name="Address" value="" type="text">
```

Although note that the function you provide to `val()` is not required, and is the cause of your problem. You can simplify the code to just this:

```js
$("#AddressId").change(function() {
  var address = $(this).val() ? $(this).find('option:selected').text() : '';      
  $("#Address").val(address).trigger("change");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="AddressId">
   <option value="">-- Please select --</option>
   <option value="1">xyz street</option>
 </select>

<input id="Address" name="Address" value="" type="text">
```

Comment: Does OP wants it to work this way? I guess he doesn't want to change the inputs value if the selected option value is empty.

Comment: His current logic wipes out the value when selecting the first option, so I simply followed that.

Answer (score 0):

I bet you have just overcomplicated it.

```js
$("#AddressId").change(function() {
  if ($(this).val()) {
    $('#Address').val($(this).find('option:selected').text());
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="AddressId">
   <option value="">-- Please select --</option>
   <option value="1">xyz street</option>
   ...
 </select>

<input id="Address" name="Address" value="" type="text">
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply add a condition `selected_value != ""` then assign the selected value if isn't empty :

```
$("#AddressId").change(function () {
    var selected_value = $(this).val();

    if( selected_value != ""){
        $("#Address").val( selected_value );
   }
});
```

Hope this helps.

```js
$("#AddressId").change(function () {
  var selected_value = $(this).val();

  if( selected_value != ""){
      $("#Address").val( selected_value );
  } 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="AddressId">
 <option value="">-- Please select --</option>
 <option value="1">xyz street</option>
 <option value="2">abc street</option>
 <option value="3">def street</option>
</select>

<input id="Address" name="Address" value="" type="text">
```